# How to identify where a package execution has spent most of the time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Team BI has a package deployed as a project on SQL Server 2012.

How can I find how long a package takes to run on a daily basis, and where it has spent most of the time?

I know that the catalog.executions view can be queried, anything else?

I am getting this request from developers:

---

Today’s BI Incremental ran without error but took far longer than usual.  The Sales Incremental took 1hour 12mins.  Yesterday it took 15 mins.  There has been no release/code changes.

The Sales ETL hits databasename on servername.  Was there something going on at the time of the load (5am)?  Anything logged?

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 :  YOu can use the below VB code in SQL agent job to find the information on packages running on sql server 2012:

```
  '...
  '   Declare and instantiate objects here.
    Dim app As New Application
  '...
  ' Create a RunningPackages collection, named pkgs, and fill it
 ' with the running packages from the application object.
    Dim pkgs As RunningPackages = app.GetRunningPackages(Nothing) 

 ' Enumerate over each package in the collection and display some data.
     For Each package As RunningPackage In pkgs
    Console.WriteLine("InstanceID: " & package.InstanceID.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("PackageDescription: " & package.PackageDescription)
    Console.WriteLine("PackageID: " & package.PackageID.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("PackageName: " & package.PackageName)
    Console.WriteLine("UserName: " & package.UserName)
     Next
     '   Insert more code here.
```

Method 2: Refer to below excellent read from Jamie Thomson which have neat and clean scripts to provide info on you're running packages:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/10/18/collecting-information-about-your-ssis-packages-ssis-nugget.aspx

Method 3: YOu can use below SQL code which i've been using:

```
     SET NOCOUNT ON
  -- Check if the SQL Server Agent is running
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
        FROM    MASTER.dbo.sysprocesses
        WHERE   program_name = N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher' ) 
BEGIN
    SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName' ,
            1 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'
END
 ELSE 
     BEGIN
    SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName' ,
            0 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'               
    RAISERROR('The SQL Server Agent is not running.', 16, 1) WITH SETERROR ;               
END
     -- Execute the script
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
        FROM    tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID(N'[tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]') ) 
DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]
GO
   CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]
(
  job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ,
  last_run_date NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  last_run_time NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  next_run_date NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  next_run_time NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  next_run_schedule_id INT NOT NULL ,
  requested_to_run INT NOT NULL ,
  request_source INT NOT NULL ,
  request_source_id SYSNAME COLLATE database_default
                            NULL ,
  running INT NOT NULL ,
  current_step INT NOT NULL ,
  current_retry_attempt INT NOT NULL ,
  job_state INT NOT NULL
)
 DECLARE @job_owner SYSNAME
  DECLARE @is_sysadmin INT
  SET @is_sysadmin = ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin'), 0)
 SET @job_owner = SUSER_SNAME()
 INSERT  INTO [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]
    EXECUTE MASTER.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs @is_sysadmin, @job_owner

UPDATE  [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]
  SET     last_run_time = RIGHT('000000' + last_run_time, 6) ,
    next_run_time = RIGHT('000000' + next_run_time, 6) ;
-----
   SELECT  j.name AS JobName ,
    j.enabled AS Enabled ,
    CASE x.running
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Running'
      ELSE CASE h.run_status
             WHEN 2 THEN 'Inactive'
             WHEN 4 THEN 'Inactive'
             ELSE 'Completed'
           END
    END AS CurrentStatus ,
    COALESCE(x.current_step, 0) AS CurrentStepNbr ,
    CASE x.running
      WHEN 1 THEN js.step_name
      ELSE NULL
    END AS CurrentStepName ,
    CASE WHEN x.last_run_date > 0
         THEN CONVERT (DATETIME, SUBSTRING(x.last_run_date, 1, 4) + '-'
              + SUBSTRING(x.last_run_date, 5, 2) + '-'
              + SUBSTRING(x.last_run_date, 7, 2) + ' '
              + SUBSTRING(x.last_run_time, 1, 2) + ':'
              + SUBSTRING(x.last_run_time, 3, 2) + ':'
              + SUBSTRING(x.last_run_time, 5, 2) + '.000', 121)
         ELSE NULL
    END AS LastRunTime ,
    CASE h.run_status
      WHEN 0 THEN 'Fail'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancel'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
    END AS LastRunOutcome ,
    CASE WHEN h.run_duration > 0
         THEN ( h.run_duration / 1000000 ) * ( 3600 * 24 )
              + ( h.run_duration / 10000 % 100 ) * 3600 + ( h.run_duration
                                                          / 100 % 100 )
              * 60 + ( h.run_duration % 100 )
         ELSE NULL
    END AS LastRunDuration ,
    js.command AS SSISPackageExecutionCommand
     FROM    [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1] x
    LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON x.job_id = j.job_id
    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON js.job_id = j.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscategories c ON j.category_id = c.category_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON x.job_id = h.job_id
                                                AND x.last_run_date = h.run_date
                                                AND x.last_run_time = h.run_time
                                                AND h.step_id = 0
 WHERE   x.running = 1
    AND js.subsystem = 'SSIS'

 DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[Temp1]
```